# The Android SDK could not be loaded Processing

Tags: android, sdk, processing

When I try to download the Android SDK when Processing doesn't find it, at 30%, it says "The Android SDK could not be loaded, Android mode will be turned off"

I'm using Windows 10 home edition, Processing 3.3.6, Processing-Android 4

Comment: I'm not sure how we can really help here. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Processing? What version are you using? Have you tried restarting your computer? Have you followed **all** of the setup steps?

Comment: I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling processing, but not restarting, I'm going to try that

Comment: @KevinWorkman That didn't work

Comment: Again, I don't know how we can help you. We don't have access to your computer, and it sounds like an intermittent problem. It sounds like something is wrong with your setup, but it's impossible for us to walk through that with you. Does it work on a different computer?

Comment: @KevinWorkman No.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I posted an issue on the Processing-Android github repository in case its a problem with the mode itself.

Comment: The issue helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/processing/processing-android/issues/421

1. Install Android Studio, open it
2. click configure, click SDK Manager, checkmark the box labeled Android 8.0 (Oreo), apply, install, copy the file path at the top, apply.
3. Open processing, in android mode, select Locate SDK Manually, paste.

Comment: What does the second checkbox do?

Comment: The second checkbox is the version of the android SDK processing needs. Checking that will install the SDK @KevinWorkman

Comment: In my case (windows, android studio 4.1), the option in 2nd step is under File / Settings, found via searching for "SDK".

Answer (score 1):

All of answers above are true, but one extra thing to do is, after installing Android Studio and the SDK you first need to add command line tool according to the processing Recommendation for the Local path of the SDK usage.

It's action is done under Android studio configure -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools. Check Command line tool.

Now it is ready to copy SDK path as mentioned by others above.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple! Download Android Studio from https://developer.android.com/studio, install it, click the "SDK Manager" button on the top right corner, [as you can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix2Ij.png). Then download the version of the SDK that you want...**make sure to download the correct version** -  the one mentioned by the error dialog from the PDE (Processing Development Environment/ Processing IDE/program/app). After it has downloaded, select the checkbox next to it, and copy the path for it, [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLOGn.png). Launch the PDE in Android mode, and when it asks you for the path, Select `Locate SDK Path manually` and paste the path there. It should work now.

On Windows, at least, **You may want to un-hide the AppData folder**, I had to, though *I'm sure it's not a requirement,* if it has worked out for you so far, skip this step!

To unhide the folder, in the Windows Explorer, go to `C:\Users\<Username>\`, select the AppData folder, and unhide it..

(Enable "`Hidden items`" under "`View`" first! Look at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bqBL.png) for reference)

..by going to `View > Hide selected items`, [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bqBL.png) and selecting "`Apply changes to this folder only`". THEN the PDE may be able to see it. **YOU MAY WANT TO HIDE THE FOLDER AFTER DOING THIS!** It is a quite important system folder, though I'm sure many people access a lot, it still needs security; ...it's better for you, I guess.